# another proof of divergence theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The following is a simple proof of divergence theorem :

$$
\begin{align}
& \phantom{={}} \iiint (\nabla\cdot F) \, dV \\
& = \iiint \frac{(∂F_x)}{∂x} \, \text{dx dy dz} + \iiint  \frac{(∂F_y)}{∂y} \, \text{dy dx dz}                              + \iiint \frac{(∂F_z)}{∂z}    \text{dz dx dy} \\
& =\iint F_x\,  \text{dy dz} + \iint F_y \, \text{dx dz} + \iint F_z \text{dx dy} \\
& =\iint F_x dS_x   +\iint F_y \, dS_y +\iint  F_z \, dS_z
\end{align}
$$
(since the projected area onto (for eg) $x$-$y$ plane is the $z$-component of area vector)

$$ =\iint (F_x+F_y+F_z)\cdot( dS_x+ dS_y+ dS_z) $$

$$ =\iint F\cdot dS$$

Is this proof enough? Then why we use the long proof given in most textbooks?

Comment: Because what you've written doesn't mean anything, sadly.

Comment: There is a problem in the very first step.  To express a triple integral as a single iterated integral with, say, the order of integration $dx dy dz$, you must assume that the region of integration has the form $f(y,z) \leq x \leq g(y,z)$ for $y,z$ in some domain in the plane.  This is rarely possible.

Comment: @PaulSiegel: Even if you assume the region is $x$-, $y$-, and $z$-"simple," this isn't a proof without a whole lot more.

Comment: That said, any suitably nice region can be approximated arbitrarily well by the union of cubes, and some version of your calculation works on a cube.  This is the idea behind many of those long proofs.

Comment: It looks more or less correct to me on a simple region. (Though the last step should be written out correctly using a parametrization of the boundary.)